# PyStringNode and json string

Tags: php, behat

I have the following feature, and I am trying to test the structure of an object.

```
  @mynet
  Scenario: Import mynet network Transactions
    Given I Import transactions for network "mynet" from "2015-09-01" to "2015-09-01"
    Then I should have 20 transactions imported
    And The first element of the transaction should be
    """
    {
            "transaction_date": "2015-09-01 19:34:17",
            "tenant_id":  1,
            "network":  "xxx",
            "network_transaction_id":  "xxxxa630514d",
            "network_merchant_name":  "xxxxx",
            "currency":  "EUR",
            "amount":  "287.40",
            "commission":  "4.31",
            "subid":  "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "enquiry_id":  0,
            "reference":  "xxxx6a630514d",
            "network_merchant_id":  "4",
            "status":  "declined",
            "network_status":  "2",
            "meta_data":  "{"short_name":"mynet"}"
    }
    """
```

there is something wrong with the `meta_data` piece. I have the feeling PyStringNode format does not convert it properly. 
Here is the part in my Behat Context for handling the PyStringNode

```
public function theFirstElementOfTheTransactionShouldBe(PyStringNode $string)
{
    $expectedFirstElement = json_decode($string->getRaw(), true);
    $realfirstelement = $this->transactions[0];
    Assert::assertEquals($realfirstelement, $expectedFirstElement);
}
```

and when running the behat test, I get the error

```
null does not match expected type "array".
```

when i replace meta_data with a simple string, all is well.....is there a special case when having json objects? how do I structure my scenario/feature?

Comment: Search for `PyStringNode` in [here](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/home) for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra quotes in surrounding your object. Remove them, it should work.

Here is the corrected version *(not tested)*:

```
@mynet
  Scenario: Import mynet network Transactions
    Given I Import transactions for network "mynet" from "2015-09-01" to "2015-09-01"
    Then I should have 20 transactions imported
    And The first element of the transaction should be
    """
    {
        "transaction_date": "2015-09-01 19:34:17",
        "tenant_id":  1,
        "network":  "xxx",
        "network_transaction_id":  "xxxxa630514d",
        "network_merchant_name":  "xxxxx",
        "currency":  "EUR",
        "amount":  "287.40",
        "commission":  "4.31",
        "subid":  "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "enquiry_id":  0,
        "reference":  "xxxx6a630514d",
        "network_merchant_id":  "4",
        "status":  "declined",
        "network_status":  "2",
        "meta_data": {
            "short_name":"mynet"
        }
    }
    """
```